# Extract JavaScript table using python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm a beginner in python and I'm trying to figure out how to extract the data from This website: https://www.tokendata.io/.  Normally I deal with HTML tables using beautiful soup, but this seems require the use of selenium. Is anyone Who Can help me. I desperately need the data for my thesis.

Comment: See [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: which table you are talking about ? atleast provide the manual steps ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean you want to load the page and extract the data found in the HTML table of div.dataTables_scrollBody   to an object in python like a tuple

```
tabletuple = [('EOS','Active','$3,272,911,705.00','Jun 2018','','','',''),('Telegrame Open Network',"Completed",'1,700,000,000.00   ','Apr 2018','','',''),...etc
```

You can do this with selenium by getting 
table by  css selector "div.dataTables_scrollBody"

below is some sample code with webdriver to get index 1 row and index 1 column of the row's text by selenium webdriver. You could use this with the code above to create a tuple of the data from the HTML table

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-file-access-from-files")
chrome_options.add_argument("--allow-running-insecure-content")
chrome_driver_path = os.path.join(driver_path, "chromedriver.exe")
print("\n ChromeDriverPath: " + chrome_driver_path)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_driver_path, 
chrome_options=chrome_options)
table_element = driver.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR,    value='div.dataTables_scrollBody')

rows = table_element.find_elements_by_xpath("./tr")
row = 1
row_elements = rows[row].find_elements_by_xpath("./td")
column = 1
text_element = row_elements[column].get_attribute("innerText")
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I tried to run your codes, but it raise me the following error:
row_elements = rows[row].find_elements_by_xpath("./td")
IndexError: list index out of range.
Printing out the list "rows" turned to be empty. 
I kind of solved the problem getting the text:
table_element=browser.find_element_by_css_selector("div.dataTables_scrollBody")
print(table_element.text)
That's enough for what I need, but now I am facing another problem: I would like to extract the data from each page of the table not just the first one. How can I do that?

Comment: you would need to make the next page of the table visible and then grab those elements again with selenium.  The best way to grab this info would be a API or endpoint call that would return this data systematically to you instead of using the UI. But if you are testing UI then yes you would have to act like an end user and make the data in the tables visible to the user before using selenium to find the data.